# How to optimize an inefficient recursive for loop in R

Tags: r

I wrote the code below to calculate the number of possible combinations in a screen locking pattern. The code itself works and generates the correct result. However, when the number of possible points increases beyond a small number, the code takes very long to run. For example, count_patterns_from("E", 8) takes more than 10 seconds. I have experimented packaging chunks of the code using the apply family of functions, but cannot seem to figure it out. I have never attempted to package a recursive for loop more efficiently and would appreciate any solutions that can speed up the code below:

```
count_patterns_from <- function(point, number_of_points, visited = c()) {
  points <- list(
    "A" = c("B", "CB", "D", "E", "F", "GD", "H", "IE"),
    "B" = c("A", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "HE", "I"),
    "C" = c("B", "AB", "D", "E", "F", "GE", "H", "IF"),
    "D" = c("A", "B", "C", "E", "FE", "G", "H", "I"),
    "E" = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "F", "G", "H", "I"),
    "F" = c("A", "B", "C", "DE", "E", "G", "H", "I"),
    "G" = c("AD", "B", "CE", "D", "E", "F", "H", "IH"),
    "H" = c("A", "BE", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "I"),
    "I" = c("AE", "B", "CF", "D", "E", "F", "GH", "H")
  )
  
  points <- lapply(points, function(x) x[order(nchar(x), decreasing = TRUE)])
  points <- lapply(points, function(x) x[!`%in%`(x, visited)])
  
  total <- 0
  
  if (number_of_points >= length(points)) return(total)
  if (number_of_points == 1) return(1)
  
  
  for (neighbor in points[[point]]) {
    
    if (!`%in%`(neighbor, visited)) {
      
      if (nchar(neighbor) > 1) {
        destination <- strsplit(neighbor, "")[[1]][1]
        over <- strsplit(neighbor, "")[[1]][2]
        
        if (!`%in%`(destination, visited)) {
          
          if (`%in%`(over, visited)) {
            total <- total + count_patterns_from(destination, number_of_points - 1, visited = unique(c(visited, paste0(point, over), point, destination, neighbor)))
          }
        }
        
      } else {
        total <- total + count_patterns_from(neighbor, number_of_points - 1, visited = unique(c(visited, point, neighbor)))
      }
    }
  }
  
  return(total)
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the purpose of this code? What do you mean with screen locking pattern etc?

Comment: Imagine a 9-button 3x3 keypad, with the buttons labeled A-I (the top row is A-B-C, etc.). The function takes two arguments: the starting letter ("point"), the number of points that can be visited ("number_of_points"). Based on those arguments, a sequence of points is created by connecting to the remaining points, provided that you do not return to the point from which you came (though you can pass over it if you already visited it). So argument "D", 3 would create the following pattern: DAB, DAE, DAF, DAG, DAH, etc, resulting in the total num of combinations. Again, code works just inefficient

Comment: You might be looking for `expand.grid`

Comment: Could you demonstrate on how to implement on the code above?

Comment: Often inefficient recursive functions can be substantially sped up using the `memoise` package or similar techniques.  This works if different branches of the recursion repeat calculations:  on the 2nd and later calculations the result is just returned from a cache.  I can't tell if this would work for yours, or if yours could be modified to make it work.

Comment: I've seen the RBloggers example of using memoise on a fibonacci sequence. I'm not sure whether it would apply here as this function simply runs through each unique combination of letters and increments the "total" by one once it's reached the end of the recursion. For example ("D", 3) has 37 unique combinations: DAB, DAE, DAF, DAG, DAH, DBA, DBC, DBE, DBF, DBG, DBI... Because it's literally just incrementing by one I'm not sure where memoise could be applied. Clearly there must be a more efficient way, I just can't figure it out

Comment: I think it wouldn't help on ("D", 3), but maybe you can normalize each call somehow:  ("a letter that appears 8 times with 3 neighbours") or something like that.  For example, in your`points` list, `A` and `C` look quite similar.